# Listing All Its Atomic Arrays given in Nested Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I ask you for your any help with the following problem. Thank you!

Assume that you are given a nested array with three slots. For example,

```
    var numbers = [1, [2,[3,4,5],[6,7,8]], [9,10,11]]
```

As you may notice, each array has three slots whether the slots are occupied by an integer or another array with three slots.

```
    [{"key1":1,"key2":"nothing","key3":[9,10,11]},{"key1":2,"key2":"nothing","key3":[6,7,8]},{"key1":9,"key2":"nothing","key3":11}]
```

My goal is roughly to list all the atomic arrays the given in the nested array and turn them into associative array. For example,

```
   [a,[b,c,d],e] -> [{key1: a, key2: X, key3: e}, {key1: b, key2: c, key3: d}]
```

If the element of an array is another array, the element might be given a name like "X".

```
    var arr = new Array();

    Array.prototype.node = function(){ 
       if (this.length == 1){
          arr.push({
             key1: this[0],
       })
       }
       else if (this.length == 2 ){
          arr.push({
             key1: this[0],
             key2: this[1],
          })
       }
       else if (this.length == 3){
          arr.push({
             key1: this[0],
             key2: "nothing",
             key3: this[2],
          })
       } 
    }

    Array.prototype.mkk = function (){
        switch(true){
           case(!this[0].isArray): {this.node()}
           case(this[1].length > 1): {this[1].node()}
           case(this[2].length > 1): {this[2].node()}
        }
    return arr
    }

    function myFunction() {
       var numbers = [1, [2,[3,[4,5,[]]], [4,[]]], [5,[]]]
      //do something like ... JSON.stringify(numbers.mkk())
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps the `typeof` keyword will be of use to you: `typeof [...] // returns 'object'` [Mozilla typeof documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

Comment: What is the purpose of `"nothing"` in your code? Also, I don't understand how this data structure is better for you: you are changing the property names `1` to `key1`, `2` to `key2` and lose the extra functions available for arrays. I don't get it. I would have understood if you wanted the transformation in the opposite direction, since you then gain functionality.

Comment: Just a quick link on [the dangers of extending native objects like `Array`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14034180/2902660)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might do as follows;

```js
function flatIntoObjects(a){
  return a.reduce((p,e,i) => Array.isArray(e) ? (p[0] = Object.assign(p[0], {["key"+ ++i]: "X"}), p.concat(flatIntoObjects(e)))
                                              : (p[0] = Object.assign(p[0], {["key"+ ++i]: e}), p), [{}]);
}
var numbers = [1, [2,[3,4,5],[6,7,8]], [9,10,11]];

console.log(flatIntoObjects(numbers));
```

Comment: Thank you. This will help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this ES6 function:

```js
function transform(arr) {
    return !Array.isArray(arr) ? arr 
        : Object.assign(...Object.keys(arr).map ( (key, i) =>
                ({ ['key' + (i+1)]: transform(arr[key]) })
            ));
}
// Sample call
const numbers = [1, [2,[3,4,5],[6,7,8]], [9,10,11]];
console.log(transform(numbers));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

I would not extend the Array object prototype for this. It is a too specific function, and really not very useful in general:

Arrays are objects of which the properties are sequential numbers. What you want here is to rename those numerical properties to `key` followed by that number, whereby you give up on the Array functionality you had first. Think of the `forEach` method, the `length` property, the `sort` method, ...etc. You give all this up, just to have property names which have `key` word in them. This does not really seem that useful.

Comment: Thank you @trincot

Comment: NB: I see you are marking several answers as accepted. This is not possible. You can only accept one.

Comment: Sorry. I realized that. Thank you again. All answers actually saved my life.